# Android slider drawer custom icon position

Tags: android, android-layout, slider, android-xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rotation="180" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rotation="180" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Big Big Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Big Big Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Big Big Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

I want to change the icon position and put it on the top position from left to right

Is anyone who can tell me how it to set this custom icon position on android slider drawer>

Thanks in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8dz2.png

Comment: Hello, yes I can help you , but add xml file and some drawings, screenshot to tell me what's your desired layot

Comment: yes sir check that image and slove my problem.. i want to change that image postion put on top

Comment: We need to see the xml for the sliding drawer if you want us to help you. (key word help)

Comment: ok, now add a xml file and I would something to it as an answer ;-)

Comment: yes sir i copy the xml file... please help me

Answer (score 1):

#### Take a look at your button:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Big Big Button" />
```

You can set for it an icon in at least four ways (like in this picture):
[image]

You need only to specify where the `Drawable` should stay.

- on the left of text:

  ```
  android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  ```
- on the right of text:

  ```
  android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  ```
- at the top, text below:

  ```
  android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  ```
- at the bottom, text above:

  ```
  android:drawableBottom="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  ```

All you need is to add to your button layout one of these possible lines.

Of course to one button, you can add more than one drawable.

> NOTE: Read also:
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Hope it help

EDIT: I haven't used `SlidingDrawer` before, so I cannot recognize, where the problem is, but always you can do a trick like this

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/handle"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        />
```

This is a button with your desired image and "transparent" background.
Try it now and I would look for another solution ;-)

SOLUTION: Please try this code:

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rotation="180" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rotation="180" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Big Big Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Big Big Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Big Big Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you still have any question please free to ask

Comment: sir i want to change the position of slider drawer icon. not in button sir.. please r u get my problem

Comment: sir i want  handle of Slidingdrawer postion of icon. please help me

Comment: change one of your existing button with this one

Comment: i used ur code.. but its getting on button like a image... but i want sliderdrawer handler icon position sir.....sliderdrawer is like a navagation sir..

Comment: i want to work with navagtion with activity soo.. i am working on the sliderdrawer

Comment: well, for me is working really good. SlidingDrawer is already highly deprecated. Check NavigationDrawer and Material elements http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: oh thx sir. but i am faceing a problem on taking a listview in fragments in navigation so for that.. if u help me please sir.. how to take listview in fragments in slide navigation

Comment: @kalyankumar all I could help I helped. as I said SlidingDraw is deprecated. Create new project with Android Studio there's at least two options with material design navigation drawer. It's easier and faster.

Comment: for that create new question on StackOverflow

Comment: hii, mark this as solution for above problem or I would delete it as not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Sliding drawer is deprecated, and is hard to use but I made a replacement. The only problem about it is that it doesn't slide like the sliding drawer, but it does apear and disapear. Here is the XML part:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >




        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#acacac"
            android:layout_height="100dp"

            android:id="@+id/etc"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Menu"
                android:id="@+id/bMenu"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"


                android:background="@drawable/button_shape_1"

                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/etc"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/menuContent">

            //content

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This will by default(on copy/paste) not be shown(half the point)

It must be a framelayout as they allow item to be layed on top of eachother(the root element that is)

The code part:

```
  RelativeLayout menuContent;
    Button showMenu;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    menuContent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuContent);
    showMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMenu);
    showMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
}

boolean menuActive = false;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bMenu:
            if(menuActive){
                menuActive = false;
                menuContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else if(!menuActive){
                menuActive = true;
                menuContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

This was copied out of a part of one of my newest games, so if it doesn't work as it sits, let me know and I will take a look at it